# Unable to delete "vm" created with prlctl

Tags: parallels

I have create a VM using:

```
prlctl create MyVM --distribution ubuntu
```

Now I can not remove it from the "Control Center"(right click "remove")?

And if I use prlctl delete:

```
prlctl delete MyVM         
Removing the VM...
Failed to remove the VM: Unable to perform the action because the virtual machine is busy. The virtual machine is currently running. Please try again later.
```

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Parallels helped, so now the "vm" can be removed.